# Does a static code-block runs more than one time in concurrent environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a static code block:

```
public class MyClass {

static {
        
        String s = "src/test/resources/dfdf.properties";
        Resource r = new FileSystemResource(s);
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        
        try {
            props.load(r.getInputStream());
            
            accessToken = props.getProperty("password");
            locationToken = props.getProperty("username");
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("We have an error for reading the access and location tokens for Brink web-service config");
        }
    }


}
```

If I understand it correctly, the static code block will run only once even we have concurrent environment. Does it correct?

Comment: it is only executed when the class is loaded into the memory. that doesn't mean each time you instantiate or call it

Comment: @Stultuske "that doesn't mean each time you instantiate or call it " - so if I need to instantiate the class again, it wont call this block again?

Comment: It will run even if you do not instantiate any instance of that class at all. I think in a simple standard java application you could say that it will run exactly once at application start. In other environments that dynamically load new classes at runtime it could be a bit more complicated. But it will always be thread-safe.

Comment: @Amongalen this is exactly I need to know. So the block will be thread-safe and run only once.

Comment: yes, but MyClass  must be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this code executed for the first time when the class loadded by class loader and you know after classes loaded all methods information and related information will be stored in method area in JVM and this information will be shared by all thread in program. so other threads only access method definition, fields, Constant pool information in this area and don't execute such static block anymore.